# Php - Notice: Undefined offset 10?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, undefined, offset

```
<?php

require "connection.php";

$cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `kelimeler` ORDER BY `numara` DESC LIMIT 10");

$i = 0;
$tr_dizi = array();
$alm_dizi = array();

while ($satir = mysql_fetch_array($cek)) {
    $tr_dizi[$i] = $satir["turkce"];
    $alm_dizi[$i] = $satir["almanca"];
    $i++;
}

$deger = rand(1,10);

setcookie("soru", $tr_dizi[$deger]);
setcookie("cevap", $alm_dizi[$deger]);

?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST["kelime"])) {
    if ($_POST["kelime"] == $_COOKIE['cevap']) {
        echo '<div class="bildirim">Richtig &#10004</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="bildirim">'.$_COOKIE['soru'].' = '.$_COOKIE['cevap'].'</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

This is a quiz game like a = b what is a ? if user send b it says 'yes!' else correct answer was 'b' php say

> Notice: Undefined offset: 10 on line 19 - 20 - 55

```
Line 19 -> setcookie("soru", $tr_dizi[$deger]);  
Line 20 -> setcookie("cevap", $alm_dizi[$deger]); 
Line 55 -> <divclass="kelime"><?php echo $tr_dizi[$deger] ?></div>
```

> when user send the answer program check it and ask new question and
>   yes or no is showing on new page i'm using cookies for that

how can i fix this error i can make error handling but i'm a new developer i want to learn thank you for everybody :)

Comment: you are still using mysql_query consider changing it to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: also,you should know the difference between mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_assoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not setting `10` as `$i` starts from `0`. And you are fetching `10` rows from database.

So the `key`s would be `0-9`. The `rand` should generate numbers between `0-9`. Try with -

```
$deger = rand(0, 9);
```

And try to avoid using `mysql`. It is deprecated now.

Comment: Omg! Thank you very much.. How I missed it :) It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes in php are zero-based, that is, an array with 10 elements indexes them as [0] through [9]. Change your initialization of `$degar` to

```
$degar = rand(0, 9);
```

and you should get rid of the error.

Comment: Thank you very much friend.. It works now :)